# Give a NiFi user permission to edit the root process group using the REST API

Tags: apache-nifi

How do I give a NiFi user permission to edit the root process group using the REST API?

My user has identity
'L=Boston, C=US, CN=John Doe'

I'm assuming I need to make a POST request to 
  /nifi-api/policies

But I am confused about how to structure the body of the request. Does the component/component reference need to refer to the root process group? Is version required? How do I refer to this user in the body?

Guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It is safe to assume that no other users exist that have this policy, so it is a policy creation, rather than an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using the dev tools I believe the correct answer is:

```
{
    "revision": {
        "version": 0
    },
    "component":{
        "resource":"process-groups/root",
        "action": "write",
        "users":[{
            "permissions":{"canRead":true,"canWrite":true},
            "component":{"identity":"L=Boston, C=US, CN=John Doe"}
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to figure this out would be to open Chrome Dev tools while you are using the UI, then add the given user to the policy you are interested in, and then look at the POST request that was made in the network section of Dev tools.